# Get Directory Path 2 Levels Up and Change the Format (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, output, windows-scripting

I am writing a large script to migrate many files at once and I will need to be able to get each file directory in a certain format.

If you look in the image below, you can see an example of a file in its directory

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NKgt.png)

The directory here is **C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Test Env\Videos on Server\2016\02\1st**

But I need it to display as **2016-02-1st** which is 2 levels up and has `dashes` instead of `slashes`

I use the code below to get the path:

```
set p=%cd%
echo %p%
pause
```

Any ideas on how to change the output?

Comment: Will it always be the 6th, 7th, and 8th folders in the path?

Comment: Yes always the same folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always the 6th, 7th, and 8th:

```
for /f "delims=\ tokens=7-9" %%a in ("%cd%") do echo %%a-%%b-%%c
```

Comment: Perfect flawless solution! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test Env\Videos on Server" %%I in (*.mp4) do (
    for %%J in ("%%~dpI..\..") do (
        for %%K in ("%%~dpI..") do (
            for %%L in ("%%~dpI.") do (
                echo %%~nxJ-%%~nxK-%%~nxL
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
```

It is of course possible to use just `*` instead of `*.mp4` to process all files found recursively in `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test Env\Videos on Server` and its subdirectories.

Another solution would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test Env\Videos on Server\*") do (
    for /D %%J in ("%%I\*") do (
        for /D %%K in ("%%J\*") do (
            echo %%~nxI-%%~nxJ-%%~nxK
        )
    )
)

endlocal
```

Which approach is better depends on what to do with the files found in the subdirectories of `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test Env\Videos on Server`, i.e. which commands are used instead of command `echo` in the most inner `for` loop. The first code expects more or less that *.mp4 files are found only three directory levels below the specified parent directory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Note: The commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** would not be really necessary here and could be omitted as the default environment for batch file execution is the same as defined with `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`.

See also the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: Thank you! I will use this if for other cases

Comment: Nice.  I was thinking about looping through the directories from beginning to end to find the last 3.  I like these clever ideas.